# How to send an item when he purchased an item? Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Good day!

I am currently creating an app that sells photos. I'm new and I can't seem to find a guide on how to send the photo to the user when he purchased the item.

Comment: Do you have some code implemented? Please explain succintly your problem.

Comment: I don't have the code for the In-App purchase of google yet, however I am trying to identify on how to send the photos. Do I need a server where the users will download the photo or Google Console will provide it?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood the problem, but you just need to give the user access to the photo location. If you have a database with a table and a table photos, you can relate them.

Comment: It's in the Drawable folder, my problem is that when I want to send newly created photos, how do I send it in the user?

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand your problem. Please explain the follwing statement: "I want to send newly created photos". If you can edit your post  with a FULLY explanation of your problem.

Comment: What I mean is that, I have a new photo to sell and I want to update it in my app. Where do I send/upload the photo so that the user can see it and will update them that the photo is for sale?

Comment: You will need a server to accomplish that. Everytime you have a new photo just upload it to the server. When the user purchases a photo you will give him access to the path of that photo.

Comment: Okay thank you for that, Can google provide the server for photos?